# Coding help for for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, char

```
{

char ch;
int count, lineCount;
count = 0;
lineCount = 0;

printf("Please enter one alphabet\n");

for (lineCount = 0; (ch = getchar()) != '\n'; lineCount++)
{
    putchar(ch-'0');
        printf("\n");

    for (count = 0; count <= (ch - '0'); count++)
        printf("%c \n", ch);
}


return 0;
}
```

This is my code so far. I need to do more stuff later but I'm just taking one step at a time. So I'd enter a letter. For example, d. 
I put that putchar there to check that ch-'0' equals to the number I want. It does. d comes out to 4. 
So in theory, I thought this code would print d out 4 times. But in  reality, it printed it out a good 30-40 times. 
It's the same with any other letter. It prints out a good 40 times. Plus, the count has no effect. I initialized it with a 5, which is obviously greater than 4. It still prints out like 40 times. 
I haven't used for loops much. I know the concept, but I perhaps I'm making a huge C language mistake.
What's wrong here??

---

haha well I only copied the parts that count. I have the main.
And isn't 4 the integer value for 'd' - '0'? that's what it printed out as in that putchar statement and I actually tried changing it into int, but it made no difference. Well, not saying you are wrong at all. I'm the one that's wrong obviously. But that was my thinking behind it. 
Please, can you explain the logistics behind it and what I should do?

Comment: First off, you're missing `int main(void)`. That might help.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that `'d'-'0'` yields `4`? Can you type out the sequence for 0,1,2,3,4 in that system?

Comment: I suspect there may be a different type of language mistake with *"Please enter one alphabet"*

Comment: An ASCII `d` is 100 and `0` is 48, so `'d' - '0'` is 52, and 52 is the *character* `4`, which might explain something (assuming ASCII or something based on it).

Comment: `'0'` = 48, `'d'` = 100.  100 - 48 != 4.  An [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) might be of help.

Comment: you need ch - ('a' - 1) if you want 'd' to = 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on `Please enter one alphabet` you can reduce your `for` loop to

```
for (lineCount = 0; (ch = getchar()) != '\n'; lineCount++)
{
        putchar(ch);
        printf("\n");

        printf("From Printf: %c \n", ch);
}
```

Note: `ch - '0'` is usually used to get the *integer* value of the *char* digit(s), `'0'` to `'9'`.

Answer (score 0):

'd' - '0' is not 4. If you refer to an ASCII chart, you'll see that the value for 'd' in decimal is 100 and the value for '0' in decimal is 48, so I would expect the inner loop to repeat 100-48 = 52 times.

Since you did a putchar, it sent a byte having the decimal value 52 to the output, which happens to correspond to the ASCII character '4'.

Note that if you typed '4' instead of 'd', you should see it loop 4 times.

The basic issue is that of the relationship between quantitative values and representations of values in a given character set.